# Find first occurrence of a file name in project in Kotlin

Tags: loops, kotlin, directory-walk, filewalker

I'd like to be able to search for "someFileName" file in a project that may contain more than one, starting at the root directory, and then stopping when I encounter the first one.  Something like a FileTreeWalk that exits early based on some condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main() {
    val found = File("${yourProjDir}").walk().find {  it.name == "${fileNameToFind}" }
    println(found?.name)
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.